# Exercise about $k[w, x, y, z]/(wz−xy, wy−x^2 , xz−y^2)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to solve the following exercise from Professor Vakil's book:

> 3.6.F. TRICKY EXERCISE. (a) Suppose $I = (wz−xy, wy−x^2 , xz−y^2) \subset k[w, x, y, z]$. Show that $\operatorname{Spec} k[w, x, y, z]/I$ is irreducible, by showing
>   that $k[w, x, y, z]/I$ is an integral domain. (This is hard, so here is
>   one of several possible hints: Show that $k[w, x, y, z]/I$ is isomorphic
>   to the subring of $k[a, b]$ generated by monomials of degree divisible
>   by 3.)

I don't really know where to start, even with the hint. I can see that $w$, $x$, $y$, and $z$, will all be nonzero in the quotient. Also there will be $wx$, $w^2$, $zy$, and $z^2$. These are all of degree 1 or 2, and they cannot be written as $a^3$, so I don't think I understand the Professor's hint.

Thanks!!!

Comment: 1. How do you show the quotient ring is a domain? 2. What does it mean for Spec to be irreducible? What is the nilradical of the quotient? Also, its spec not speck.

Comment: @PrinceM: 1) That's the question :o 2) I don't understand.  The irreducibility follows from k[w,x,y,z]/I being a domain. That's the part I need help with.

Comment: @PrinceM It's not Speck, it's Spec k where the space disappeared because it always does in math mode.

Comment: Don't focus too much on $k[x,y,z,w]/I$. Instead, try to construct a homomorphism $k[x,y,z,w]\to k[a,b]$ where the image is the given subring, and the kernel is $I$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/227255/121097

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142490